# Hyper-V Core with Basic UPS options

Tags: hyper-v, ups

Good morning, running Dell T610 server with Hyper-V Core, just a few VMs, hardware Firewall & Router. My old Belkin UPS failed today so I need to replace asap at cheap cost where possible probably meaning UPS without shutdown software.

I have read that basic UPS connected via USB would trick server 2008 into being a bulky laptop with power management options in control panel allowing the user to trigger host shutdown after say  5 minutes?

Is this true & would I be able to manage this on Hyper-V Core? Not after anything major just some surge protection and option to gracefully shutdown the host?

Many thanks

Gary

Comment: Hmm, some people eh, why down-vote an honest question? I have no money to just go out & buy UPS then find it doesn't quite do what I need so I ask some advice from people who may have been in same position to save some money?

Comment: I know this works on Windows 2008 - curious to know if it does on a Hyper-V Core

Comment: I'm really not sure it will as there is no access to control panel even with CoreConfig. There must be a solution to UPS with Core but I am a guessing its an expensive one ruling many SME/home users out. 

Odd thing is, on my old Belkin UPS, I just connected both power leads direct to the UPS, I noted when the UPS failed it did actually power down the host Hyper-V server gracefully, I had never setup any software or scripts, baffled how that worked!